# Screen blinking issue when updating Userform

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a teleprompter by using Word VBA and Userform. I made it by dragging a Userform's label to the top every xxx millisecond to give the text scrolling effect.
My problem is the blinking screen as probably the code runs much faster than the graphic update.
Is there a way out to prevent the blinking screen?

**EDIT:**

Below is the code

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Dim i As Double
    Dim dblScrollHeight As Double
    Dim sglPause As Single, sglStart As Single
    Dim dblEndPos As Double

    If KeyAscii = 32 Then bolScroll = Not bolScroll
    If bolScroll = True Then
        dblEndPos = 50
        dblScrollHeight = 0.1
        sglPause = 0.0005 'Alter this number to adjust scroll speed.

        i = dblCurrTop
        Do
            sglStart = Timer 'Set Start time.
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until Timer - sglStart > sglPause

            i = i - dblScrollHeight
            dblCurrTop = i
            'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Me.lblPrompter.Top = dblCurrTop
            'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            If i + Me.lblPrompter.Height <= dblEndPos Then bolScroll = False
        Loop Until bolScroll = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not include attachments to external files. Instead, include the relevant code you need help with in your question.

Comment: Why not just use Word in Continuous Scroll mode, and have the macro Scroll the Page View instead?  Seems far less bodgy to me.  Or, perhaps a Motion Path Animation in PowerPoint?  This could be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...

Comment: Depending on how quickly the code is executing/looping, I'd guess you are right that it's faster than the form is updating... As mentioned before, can you please include your code in the question for further investigation?

Comment: @Chronocidal: Are you referring to the auto scroll/ small scroll? They're not so smooth. I also think Powerpoint is better with its transition and animation but it's more convenient to edit and navigate pages of text in Word.
OOT: Sorry, is it prohibited to attach an external file?